# SQL - add column with auto increment via select

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table like below in PostgreSQL

table1

```
date_time               | make   | model | miles | reg_no | age_months
----------------------------------------------------------------------
2016-09-28 20:05:03.001 | toyota | prius | 10200 | 1111   | 22
2016-09-28 20:05:03.001 | suzuki | sx4   | 10300 | 1122   | 12
2016-09-28 20:03:03.001 | suzuki | sx4   | 11200 | 1133   | 34
2016-09-28 20:02:03.001 | toyota | prius | 15200 | 1144   | 28
2017-05-28 20:11:03.001 | toyota | prius | 15500 | 1144   | 36
```

I need to add a column `record_num` which starts from 1 and auto increment by 1 for every record to the table - I cannot alter the table due to permission restrictions, so it need to be done via `select` operation.

The expected output is like as below.

table2

```
date_time               | make   | model | miles | reg_no | age_months | record_num
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2016-09-28 20:05:03.001 | toyota | prius | 10200 | 1111   | 22         | 1
2016-09-28 20:05:03.001 | suzuki | sx4   | 10300 | 1122   | 12         | 2
2016-09-28 20:03:03.001 | suzuki | sx4   | 11200 | 1133   | 34         | 3
2016-09-28 20:02:03.001 | toyota | prius | 15200 | 1144   | 28         | 4
2017-05-28 20:11:03.001 | toyota | prius | 15500 | 1144   | 36         | 5
```

Edit:

The date-time is not in order in `table1`. But the `record_num` needs to be in the order as in the `table1`.

Comment: There is no such thing as "the order of the table". Rows in a relational database are ***NOT*** sorted. The ***only*** (really: the only) way to get a specific order is to use an `order by`.

Comment: check my answer. i think it suits your condition

Answer (score 1):

Use a [window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html):

```
select date_time, 
       make, 
       model, 
       miles,
       reg_no, 
       age_months, 
       row_number() over (order by date_time) as record_num
from the_table
order by date_time;
```

Comment: The order of `record_num` needs to be in the order of the data in the original table - `table1` - I just edited the question

Comment: Quite ok, but row_number() over(order by some_column) will not be unique if this column is not unique - the same dates will give you the same row_numbers... I'll sugest 'row_number() over()' and subquery with order by date.

Comment: @Jendrusk: `row_number()` **will** always return unique numbers. You are confusing that with `rank()` or `dense_rank()`. See here: http://rextester.com/LSZ41415

Comment: @user3206440: there is no such thing as "the order of the data" in a relational database. Rows in a table are ***NOT*** sorted in any way. The **only** way to get a guaranteed order of rows (or the numbers) is to use an `order by`  statement. There is no other way.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - Sorry - You are right, I was wrong

Answer (score -2):

use row_number to generate sequence:

```
Select row_number() over(order by reg_no) Sno,* from Table1
```

OR

if there is no unique column then create a sequence and then use it with select :

```
     CREATE SEQUENCE seq_person
      MINVALUE 1
      START WITH 1
     INCREMENT BY 1

     select NEXT VALUE FOR seq_person AS FirstUse,* from table1
```

Comment: `select NEXT VALUE FOR seq_person` is invalid for Postgres

Comment: yes i do know that. you just google that how to create sequence in postgresql